# Creating an MVC form using partial views each with complex models not binding to main model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, model-binding, mvc-editor-templates

I'm working on a form that has a main model being passed to the view.  The model has sub-models within it, with partial views to render that content.  The problem is that when I fill out the form, only those parameters on the main form get bound back to the model when the form is submitted.

I tried changing the Html.RenderPartial to a Html.EditorFor, and while it fixed my model binding problem, it removed all of my html formatting from the partial view.

Is there a way I can either bind my partial view elements to the main form model, or keep the html structure of my partial view using EditorFor?

Below is my code (I chopped out a bunch of stuff - especially from my main view - to try to simplify what I'm looking for).

This is my model:

```
public class ShipJobs
{
    public String Job { get; set; }
    public String Quote { get; set; }
    public String PartName { get; set; }
    public String Rev { get; set; }
    public String Customer { get; set; }
    public String CustomerName { get; set; }
    public String TrackingNumber { get; set; }
    public Int32 ShippedQuantity { get; set; }
    public Boolean Certs { get; set; }
    public Double ShippingCharges { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }
    public String SelectedFreightTerms { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FreightTerms { get; set; }
    public String SelectedContact { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Contacts { get; set; }
    public String SelectedShipVia { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ShipVia { get; set; }
    public Models.GreenFolders.Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public AddressType Type { get; set; }
    public String ShipToId { get; set; }
    public String ContactName { get; set; }
    public String AddressName { get; set; }
    public String Line1 { get; set; }
    public String Line2 { get; set; }
    public String City { get; set; }
    public String State { get; set; }
    public String Zip { get; set; }

    public String Phone { get; set; }
    public SelectList ShipToAttnDropDown { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ShipToDropDown { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ShipJobs(String Job, Models.Shipping.ShippingModel.ShipJobs Packlist, Models.GreenFolders.Address ShipAddress, String Submit = "")
{
    var Model = new Models.Shipping.ShippingModel.ShipJobs();

    if (Submit == "loadjob")
    {
        var shippingHelper = new BLL.Shipping.ShippingMethods(_company);
        Model = shippingHelper.GetShipJobModel(Job);
        Model.Address = shippingHelper.GetShipAddress(Job);
    }
    else if (Submit == "createpacklist")
    {

    }

    ViewBag.Company = _company.ToString();
    return View(Model);
}
```

Main View:

```
@model Models.Shipping.ShippingModel.ShipJobs

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShipJobs";
    String Company = ViewBag.Company.ToString();
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ShipJobs", "Shipping", FormMethod.Post, new { Class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <!-- Basic Form Elements Block -->
        <div class="block">
            <!-- Basic Form Elements Title -->
            <div class="block-title">
                <h2>Load <strong>Job</strong></h2>
            </div>
            <!-- END Form Elements Title -->
            <!-- Basic Form Elements Content -->
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ShipJobs", "Shipping", FormMethod.Post, new { Class = "form-horizontal form-bordered" }))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Job Number</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Job, new { id = "example-text-input", Name = "Job", Class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-actions">
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="submit" value="loadjob"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Load Job Info</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i> Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @if (Model.Address != null && Model.Address != null)
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
            //Html.RenderPartial("../Shared/_Address", Model.ShipInfo);
        }


    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Quote)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Company)
</div>
}
```

Partial view:

```
@model Models.GreenFolders.Address

<!-- Block -->
<div class="block">
    <div class="block-title">
        @if(Model.Type == Models.GreenFolders.AddressType.Shipping)
        {
            <h2 style="float: right; margin-top: -9px; margin-right: -10px;">
                <div class="dropdown shiptoddl">
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="shiptoddl" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                        @Model.ShipToDropDown.Where(x => x.Selected).FirstOrDefault().Text
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        @foreach (SelectListItem selectlistitem in Model.ShipToDropDown)
                        {
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-value="@selectlistitem.Value" data-selected="@selectlistitem.Selected">@selectlistitem.Text</a></li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
                @*@Html.DropDownList("shiptoddl", (SelectList)Model.ShipToDropDown, new { @class = "shiptoddl", id = "shiptoddl" })*@
            </h2>
        }
        <h4><strong>@Model.Type.ToString()</strong> Address</h4>
    </div>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("../Shared/_AddressDetails", Model); }
</div>
<!-- END Block -->
```

Comment: You cant have nested forms (its invalid html and not supported!). A partial wont work unless you pass the prefix (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612442/how-to-persist-data-models-passed-to-partial-views/27612476#27612476)), but the best solution is the `EditorFor()` but you need to create a custom `EditorTemplate` for `Address` that contains the controls and formatting your want

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I'm not worried about the nested forms thing, my action handles it perfectly.  Do you have any examples of how to turn a formatted partial view into an EditorTemplate?  I couldn't find anything similar in my research prior to asking the question.  As a backup, the prefix solution will work great, but I'd rather learn how to use the EditorTemplate properly.  Thanks!

Comment: You should be worried, its invalid and not supported equally across different browsers and even if its working for you now on one browser, it may break for a newer version (there are plenty of questions/answers on SO about this - DON'T DO IT). As for the template, add a view to `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` named `Address.cshtml` and copy the your partial view into it.

Comment: Almost there... I'm using the override specifying my editor template name (since it doesn't match my model's property name).  That fixed the formatting issues, but it doesn't send values of the editor template back to the form submit.  I also removed the inner form, since you were correct (I didn't need it at all, my outer form already handled it - thanks for the tip).  Do you need the updated code?

Comment: You cant use the overload that specifies the editor name (that wont correctly add the prefix so you will still end up with `name="City"` instead of `name="Address.City"` which you need for binding to your `ShipJobs` model. The name of the template needs to match the name of the `class` (the name of the property is irrelevant) so if you have typeof `Address` then the template needs to be `Address.cshtml`

Comment: Got it, thanks a ton Stephen!  The issue I was seeing with my model not binding correctly was because my partial view displayed it's model contents not using DisplayFor or TextBoxFor or any other means of keeping the binding intact.  That's why, when I had the default editor template for my model, it worked perfectly.  Just leaving this trail in case anyone else has the same issue as me.

Comment: And just a few other comments: its `new { @class = "form-control" }`, and don't use `new { Name = ".." }` (never try to override the `name` attribute unless you want binding to fail)