# Passing a model to a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an _Address partial view. This partial view contains all of the address fields that match the Address Model. At the top of this view I set the model like this:
@model Data.Address

In my CustomerInfo view I try the following to render the Address fields as part of my form:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Partial/_Address.cshtml")
```

**The error I am getting is:**

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Data.Customer',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Data.Address'.

I am assuming I am getting this error because the model declared in my CustomerInfo view is of type Data.Customer and it is automatically trying to pass it to my _Address view which has a model of type Data.Address in it.

What is the proper way to make this flow properly? I noticed there is also an @Html.RenderPartial("ViewName", model) helper but have no idea how to pass it Data.Address since the primary model in my CustomerInfo view is Data.Customer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess that your primary model `Data.Customer` already has one or more properties of type `Data.Address` that you would like to display. So you would use the `@Html.Partial` helper and pass the value of this property like that:

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName", Model.SomeAddressProperty)
```

As an alternative to using the `Html.Partial` helper you could use Editor/Display templates. They work by convention. So rename your `_Address.cshtml` partial to `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Address.cshtml` and then inside your main view use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeAddressProperty)
```

or if the partial doesn't contain input fields or forms you could use a display template: `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Address.cshtml` and then:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.SomeAddressProperty)
```

The convention here is the name and location of the template. Since the type of the `SomeAddressProperty` is `Address`, ASP.NET MVC will look for the corresponding `Address.cshtml` template.

If your main view model doesn't have an address property you should simply go ahead and add one or more such properties and populate them in the controller action rendering the main view. Then you can call the partial for each of those properties.

Comment: Since I am using EF6 and Customer has an AddressId field I was able to do @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address) and in my Address.cshtml EditorTemplate my model declared at the top is @model Data.Address. Everything is populating fine, although I am wondering how saving works. I have it working for the customer fields but not sure how to save a new address to the address table beforehand. Also, when should I use EditorTemplates vs PartialViews. In this case Address.cshtml is all fields that will be part of a form so does it make more sense to use EditorTemplate?

Comment: Using `EditorTemplate` which will correctly prefix your controls (e.g. `<input name="Address.Street" ..>` which will be correctly bound to property `Address` on postback. Using a partial will result in `<input name="Street"` ..>` unless you also pass the prefix to the partial (e.g.as per [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612442/how-to-persist-data-models-passed-to-partial-views/27612476#27612476))

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't pass `Data.Customer` to your main view, but only 'Data'. This is more flexible, all your have to do then is fix the references inside the main view, so instead of `@Model.FirstName`, you use `@Model.Customer.FirstName`. This way, you can call your partial view with a more explicit `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Partial/_Address.cshtml", @Model.Address)`.