# How to use editor templates from within a razor page that resides in an area?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

How can I use editor templates when using razor pages? I'm also using areas as a structural pattern.

I see no output when I call `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Something)`. But, I do see the content of a custom display template when using `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Something)`.

My project tree looks like the following ...

- Areas

  - Identity

    - Pages

      - ... my various pages
- Pages

  - Shared

    - DisplayTemplates

      - string.cshtml (for example)
    - EditorTemplates

      - string.cshtml (again, example)

With this structure, I'm seeing my display templates being used but not my editor templates.

How do I use editor templates when also using razor pages & areas?

[image: visual studio project explorer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ryan, I've tried to repeat your codes to find out the answer and found that `@Html.EditorFor()` and `@Html.DisplayFor()` will cause errors in `partial` view. 
But `@Html.Raw()` and `@Html.TextBoxFor()` works well.
There is no clear answer for the reason of`@Html.EditorFor()` and `@Html.DisplayFor()` which I'm still looking for.

**/Pages/Shared/DisplayTemplates/string.cshtml**

```
@model RazorPages62921534.Models.User


<h1>DisplayTemplates</h1>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Id): @Html.Raw(Model.Id)
```

**/Pages/Shared/DisplayTemplates/string.cshtml**

```
@model RazorPages62921534.Models.User


<h1>EditorTemplates</h1>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name): @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
```

**Areas/Identity/Pages**

```
@page
@model RazorPages62921534.Areas.Identity.Pages.IdentityIndexModel

@{

        var user = new RazorPages62921534.Models.User() {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Ada"
        };
}


@Html.Partial("~/Pages/Shared/DisplayTemplates/string.cshtml", user)


@Html.Partial("~/Pages/Shared/EditorTemplates/string.cshtml", user)
```

[image]

> Test

[image]

**Related Link：**
[How to pass a nested model value in @Html.Partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339272/how-to-pass-a-nested-model-value-in-html-partial)
[Passing a model to a partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519520/passing-a-model-to-a-partial-view)

> Did I misunderstand your needs? Please let me know and I will follow
> this up.