# How to avoid view code duplication in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I've made a very simple mockup of my problem.

If i have a complex person viewModel:

```
 public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<DogViewModel> Dogs { get; set; }
}

public class DogViewModel
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

And i have 2 views :  to edit person and create a person :

```
@model Custom.Models.PersonEditViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit Person</h2>

<div class="PersonDataArea">
    //this contain identical html in Create and Edit view
</div>
<div class="SelectDogAre">
    //this contain identical html in Create and Edit view
</div>

<input type="button" value="save" />





@model Custom.Models.PersonCreateViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create Person</h2>

<div class="PersonDataArea">
    //this contain identical html in Create and Edit view
</div>
<div class="SelectDogAre">
    //this contain identical html in Create and Edit view
</div>

<input type="button" value="save"/>
```

And of course 2 ViewModels for each view :

```
public class PersonEditViewModel
    {
        public PersonViewModel Person { get; set; }
    }




public class PersonCreateViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel Person { get; set; }
}
```

**Question :**

as you can see i have 2 identical areas in Create and Edit views, and i want to avoid to suplicate code. I cant use Partial views because model in partial view will not be bound on post. How to avoid duplication of the view code??

Comment: "I can't use partial views" - that's a flawed statement. There's no reason you can't?

Comment: How do you bind data partial view to Mainview on post request?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Do you mean, how do you bind data into your partial view? Or how does the partial view pass the data back in the form POST?

Comment: How does partial view pass data back on post?

Comment: If `PersonEditViewModel` and `PersonCreateViewModel` are identical and generate identical html, why do you have separate view models? And partials wont bind unless you pass the main model to the partial or you specify the `HtmlFieldPrefix` ([Refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612442/how-to-persist-data-models-passed-to-partial-views/27612476#27612476)).

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to use a Partial View.

First of all, you don't need two separate View Models. Just the `PersonViewModel` is enough.

Then you'll create a partial view `_PersonEdit.cshtml` (by the way you are missing the form in your code):

```
@model Custom.Models.PersonViewModel

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="PersonDataArea">
        //this contain identical html in Create and Edit view
    </div>
    <div class="SelectDogAre">
        //this contain identical html in Create and Edit view
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="save"/>
}
```

And, two Views for Create and Edit:

Create:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create Person</h2>

@Html.Partial("_PersonEdit", Model)
```

Edit:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit Person</h2>

@Html.Partial("_PersonEdit", Model)
```

Alternatively, you can create only one view for both actions, and pass the `ViewBag.Title` from the controller to the view.

Comment: And if submit actions are different?

Comment: When you use `Html.BeginForm()` with no action name specified, the action name will be the same as the original GET action, so you don't need to be worried about that. 
However, if you need to pass different parameters or for other reasons, you can put the form inside the views (create and edit), and not in the partial view.

Comment: @MikeDebela, what for the last phrase?

Comment: "Alternatively, you can create only one view for both actions"

Comment: You can pass the submit action name from the controller to the view using ViewBag, and then specify the action name in your form.

Comment: What if i want to have separate viewModels for create and edit? And i want to have  SelectDogAre and PersonEdit in separate partial views... is it possible so that data inside those partial views are posted with the main view?

Comment: Yes, you can have them in separate partial views. Update your question, so I can give you a better answer.