# MVC razor view dropdownbox with items from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to MVC.Net and razorviews.
I have a model that contains a list of cards. I want to show this list in a dropdownbox inside my view. But I am not allowed. From an example, I found this code and made a try:

Class that the list is made out of:

```
public class CardType
{
    public CardType(string cardTypeName)
    {
        this.CardTypeName = cardTypeName;
    }

    public string CardTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

Model:

```
public class MyCardsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<PaymentCard> PaymentCards { get; set; }
    public AddPaymentcard PaymentCardInformation { get; set; }
}

public class AddPaymentcard
{
   public string CardTypeName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CardTypeList
    {
        get
        {
        return _cardTypes.Select(x => new SelectListItem {Value = x.CardTypeName, Text = x.CardTypeName}).ToList(); 
        }
    }

    public List<CardType> _cardTypes;
 }
```

Controller-methods:

```
    // GET: /MyCards/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        MyCardsViewModel viewModel = new MyCardsViewModel();
        var user = _userRepository.GetUser(userId);

        viewModel.PaymentCards = user.PaymentCards; //Don't mind this, it is something else :)
        var cardTypeList = _cardTypeRepository.GetCardTypes();

        viewModel.PaymentCardInformation=new AddPaymentcard 
        {
           _cardTypes = cardTypeList
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

 //Get: MyCards/AddPaymentcard
    public ActionResult AddPaymentcard()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Views:

Index-view that takes in MyCardsViewModel and adds a partial view AddPaymentcard.cshtml:

```
 @model Kvittering.TaxiFinans.Web.Models.MyCardsViewModel
 (...)
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/MyCards/AddPaymentcard.cshtml", @Model.PaymentCardInformation );
```

AddPaymentcard-view:

```
 @model Kvittering.TaxiFinans.Web.Models.AddPaymentcard

 (...)
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CardTypeName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CardTypeName, @Model.CardTypeList)
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can anyone help me with this? :/

Comment: It would need to be `get { return new SelectList(_cardTypes, "CardTypeName", "CardTypeName"); }` - you need to specify both the `Value` and `Text` properties

Comment: And you may as well make the signature `public SelectList CardTypeList {..}`, but in any case the property should be `public SelectList CardTypeList { get; set; }` and the controller should be responsible for setting the value (`List<CardType> _cardTypes;` would not be required)

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be if you `Select` a `new SelectListItem`, this way you stop using hardcoded strings, and you will be sure that you obtain what you want.

```
public class AddPaymentcard
{
   public string CardTypeName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CardTypeList
    {
        get { return _cardTypes.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.CardTypeName, Text = x.CardTypeName }); }
    }

    public List<CardType> _cardTypes;
 }
```

You have to correct this line if your view model is type of `MyCardsViewModel`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PaymentCardInformation.CardTypeName, @Model.PaymentCardInformation.CardTypeList)
```

Comment: Not really necessary, and it a bit pointless to add `.ToList()` when the property is `IEnumerable`

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are right about `.ToList()` i was doing it from habit. I think it's a better than using `SelectList`, because you don't have **hardcoded string** and you are sure that you obtain what you want a collection of `SelectListItem`.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to remove the build-errors. But when running, I get a nullpointer in the view on line " @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CardTypeName, Model.CardTypeList)" with errormessage:
      An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_qzig3nv5.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Either way is fine, but OP's issue was that he used the wrong constructor

Comment: @TorK see my updated code, i think you mean `@Model.PaymentCardInformation.CardTypeList`

Comment: @TorK, There is something wrong with your view because the model is `MyCardsViewModel`, not `AddPaymentcard`

Comment: @adricadar, I suspect it would also need to be `m => m.PaymentCardInformation.CardTypeName`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nice catching this, i didn't see it

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to add both models. I use model MyCardsViewModel that contains the model AddPaymentcard. See the code in the edited question.

Comment: @TorK Change the line as i mentioned in my answer for `@Html.DropDownListFor`.

Comment: I am so sorry. I tried to post only the relevant code. But after adding the new code, I see that more information is needed. See my updated question. Thank you guys for helping me with this. Is my problem that I send an empty model from my AddPaymentcard-controller?

Comment: @TorK Can you remove `@` from the places where is not needed? like  `@Html.Partial("~/Views/MyCards/AddPaymentcard.cshtml", Model.PaymentCardInformation );`

Comment: @TorK, Your use of a partial just wont work. Have a look at the html you generating - its `<select name="CardTypeName" ..>` which wont post back and bind to you model. It would need to be `<select name="PaymentCardInformation.CardTypeName" ..>`. Don't use partials for this, the correct approach is to use `EditorTemplates`. Alternatively, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612442/how-to-persist-data-models-passed-to-partial-views/27612476#27612476)