# Why use EditorFor over PartialView to render a partial view in MVC 4.5+

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4.5+, and I'm trying to understand why one would want to render a partial view utilizing Html.EditorFor rather than Html.PartialView.

What I've found is that EditorFor "respects the model hierarchy", which I've gather to mean that, for an input in a view rendered by EditorFor, input names/ids reflect the nested levels of the calling model, and that PartialViews don't do this.

However, in the following partial view:

```
@model someModel
...
@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.complexObject.property)
...
```

will render the textbox as

```
<input id="complexObject_property" name="complexObject.property" ... >
```

when rendered via Html.PartialView, at least in MVC 4.5+.  Which seems to me to be respecting the model hierarchy pretty well.

I understand that DisplayFor and EditorFor will tell the framework to automagically look into the ~/*Templates folder to return views for views called by these controls.  So, the only thing I can think of at the moment is that we'd use Display/EditorFor to allow for this sort of file/folder structure & automagic rendering that is a bit more semantic than looking in a "Shared" folder for a specifically named partial.

As it stands now, even Microsoft's docs seem to imply that Html.EditorFor is intended to be used only to render a single input, not a view: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Your specifying the fully qualified name - `m => m.complexObject.property` so of course it generates `name="complexObject.property"`. `EditorFor()` is not intended for only a single input. In fact is more often used with complex objects and collections to generate the correct name attributes for complex models. Using partials generally means having to pass the prefix to the partial as per [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612442/how-to-persist-data-models-passed-to-partial-views/27612476#27612476)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assume you have a model, like so:

```
public class ExampleModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Furthermore, assume you have this view, called ExampleModel.cshtml, in the EditorTemplates folder, in /Shared:

```
@model ExampleModel

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
```

To continue our assumptions, let's say you have this model as well:

```
public class ExampleListModel
{
    public ICollection<ExampleModel> Examples { get; set; }
}
```

With a view for ExampleListModel, you can do something like this:

```
@model ExampleListModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Examples)
```

The Razor engine will look for (and find, in this case) a view that matches the name of the "item" class (in my example, ExampleModel). When it does, it will iterate through the collection, generating a row for each item in ExampleListModel.Examples. As a side effect, it also names the controls in such a way that the collection can be posted to the controller in a manner that the default model binder understands. So the generated markup may look like

```
<label for="Examples[0].Name">Name</label>
<input id="Examples[0].Name" name="Examples_0__Name" value="Fee" />
<input id="Examples[0].ID" name="Examples_0__ID" value="1" />

<label for="Examples[1].Name">Name</label>
<input id="Examples[1].Name" name="Examples_1__Name" value="Fi" />
<input id="Examples[1].ID" name="Examples_1__ID" value="2" />

<label for="Examples[2].Name">Name</label>
<input id="Examples[2].Name" name="Examples_2__Name" value="Fo" />
<input id="Examples[2].ID" name="Examples_2__ID" value="3" />
```

and so on, with the indexes incrementing accordingly.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, thank you.  Very clear and non-ambiguous examples.