# setting the TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix when dynamically adding a partialview to the page

Tags: jquery, templates, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a page of tabular data - it is a list of hotel room information
I want to be able to allow the user to pick which room they want, and specify the people in that room - which is basically just a dropdownlist for adults/children.
however, i would also like to add multiple droppers based on how many rooms they require.
I have been doing this by making an ajax call to an action method which returns a partial view of the dropdowns thus

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("[+]"
                , "AddNewRoom"
                , new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                    UpdateTargetId = "rooms"
                })
```

which calls this method:

```
public ActionResult AddNewRoom()
{
    var model = new SelectedRoomVM();
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SelectedRoomVM.cshtml", model);
}
```

so, no problems so far. until that is, i try to post that data back and the markup that is generated is incorrect.
the single row of droppers geenerated when the page loads of course names the dropdowns correctly, something along the lines of

```
Rows[0].SelectedRooms[0].Adults
```

but the dynamically generated ones are simply named

```
Adults
```

the way the table is being generated is by using editortemplates

so along the lines of

```
    @model hotelrowVM
....
    @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Rows) //a table row
```

renders

```
    @model roomVM
...
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SelectedRooms) // the droppers
```

i have done a bit of searching around for ways to correctly set the HtmlFieldPrefix for the template but i am having no luck. 
could anyone suggest how i might achieve this please?

thanks

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612442/how-to-persist-data-models-passed-to-partial-views/27612476#27612476) but I suggest you would be better off using the `BeginCollectionItem` helper

Comment: hi stephen, I had been doing that, but because the item being added is nested twice, it doesnt pick up the top level